# How to map sub collection to json_serializable nested class?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

json_serializable supports nested classes:

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/json#generating-code-for-nested-classes

My goal is to have a Parent class with a Child member, and I want the firestore to look like:

`Collection(Parent) -> {parentId} -> Collection(Child) -> {childId}`

What is not clear is how the firestore that backs this model is supposed to be structured and accessed.

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This could help https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore-odm/subcollections/ but it's not ready for production.

In the meantime, I'd create instances (with json_serializable) programmatically, like:

```dart
QuerySnapshot subCollQuerySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("maincoll") //
    .doc(mainDoc.id) //
    .collection("subcoll") //
    .get();
for (var subCollDoc in subCollQuerySnapshot.docs) {
  MySubCollClass mySubCollInstance = MySubCollClass.fromJson(subCollDoc.data());
  // ... add mySubCollInstance to your mainInstance's list
}
```